# VBA record data from two drop down boxes in separate columns

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't used VBA for a while so a little rusty!

I have a user form (created in VBA) thats pulling data into a combo box from an Excel worksheet.
I also have a button that records the data that the combo box is displaying, that goes into a seperate work sheet. It also adds a row so records the data to a new row.

Also on the user form, I have a label that I also need to record data from. I need to record this data into a different column?

Any ideas how this would be done? I can only figure out how to record data from the combo box.

T

Record data from a combo box, and record data from a label into two separate columns.

Comment: Welcome Tommy! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: As a label cannot be modified by the user, this makes not much sense. Are you talking about a TextBox? A Label has no `Value`, the text that is displayed can be read/set with `Caption`. A TextBox has a `Value`-property.